# find conflict classes within dayname and class_start time 09:00:00 and class_end time 12:00:00

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an application in which user can add classes  within certain day like monday, wedenusday and friday with  class start time and class end time.i have to show search result for classes available but not already attending class.suppose user is attending some class on monday during class start at 09:00:00 and class_end at ![12:00:00][1].if any other class available(after search) in that time (like moday class start at 09:00:00 and class_end at 12:00:00 ) than that class will be conflict class .so i have to find all the conflict class and filtered available class(means after removing conflict class)  using php and mysql

Comment: can you please post some code which shows how far you got to?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a homework site, please do some research on your task, show the progress and then the stackoverflow community will help you out...